# Configuring SSL in JHipster

Tags: ssl, webpack, https, jhipster

I am currently trying to implement a ssl into my current Jhipster application.
So far i have generated a certificate using keytool -genkey -alias iroApp -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650 .

In application-dev.yml i changed the server options from:

```
server:
    port: 8080
```

to:

```
server:
    port: 8443
ssl:
    key-store: keystore.p12
    key-store-password: myPassword
    keyStoreType: PKCS12
    keyAlias: myApplicationName
```

In proxy.conf.json:
From

```
{
"*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "loglevel": "debug"
}
```

}

To

```
{
"*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8443",
    "secure": true,
    "loglevel": "debug"
}
```

}

In webpack.dev.js i have changed the target ip ports(from 8080 to 8443) and the secure from false to true.

When i enter on the page i get the "This site can’t be reached.localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED"

Is there something i forgot to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your key-alias needs to be all lowercase.  It fails silently if you have a capital letter in the alias.  You also are missing an indentation in your config, and you shouldn't mix snake-case and camelCase config variables.

Your final config should look like:

```
server:
    port: 8443
    ssl:
        key-store: keystore.p12
        key-store-password: myPassword
        key-store-type: PKCS12
        key-alias: myapplicationname
```

This was reported and fixed recently in the generator code ([issue link](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7547))